# Can I configure JMeter to accept POST request as a response?

Tags: flask, server, jmeter, benchmarking

In my application, the request cycle goes like this:

I send a post request to my server then it sends a post request back. JMeter would calculate the time delay between the request and response of the first POST request.

But I want it to calculate the time delay between the time request was sent to the server vs the time when my server sends the post request back to me.

Is there a way to do this in Jmeter?

Comment: Do you mean server sends post request back is it next redirect? what is the HTTP status code you are receiving in headers of the browser?

Comment: When I send a post request to my server, it does some computation and sends a post request back to me. I think the status code is 200.

Comment: If you just need to calculate the response time server took send response why it would matter if it is post request r anything else, Have you tried anything?

Comment: It takes very less time to give a response to my first request, it takes way more time for my server to send back the post request.